# Creating a falling ball map

Tags: code-golf, string, random

#### Introduction

For the ones who never heard of this game before. You are playing a ball which needs to survive as long as possible. This is done by moving to the left or right, going to the holes. Since the map moves upwards, you need to go downwards to survive longer. If you [search](https://www.google.nl/search?tbm=isch&q=falling+ball+game&cad=h) for images, you probably know which game I mean.

#### The Task

Given a positive integer *n*, output a falling ball map of *n* layers. Between the layers, there are 4 newlines. The width of the layer is made up of 25 underscore characters, with **one** hole of length 5. That means that the total width is equal to 30. This is randomly shifted after each layer. An example of a valid layer is:

```
_______________     __________
```

The hole can also be at the edges, as if the layer is like a cylinder:

```
  _________________________
```

Note that there are 2 leading spaces and 3 trailing spaces. Making a *single* hole of width 5.

#### Test cases

For *n*=4, this is a valid output:

```
_______________     __________





______     ___________________





_______________________     __





  _________________________
```

Note: the holes must be *uniformly* distributed. Trailing and/or leading newlines are allowed.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the submission with the least amount of bytes wins!

Comment: @DonMuesli Haha, that can happen to anyone :p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Pyth, 19 bytes

```
VQ.>+*\_25*d5O30*b4
```

[Try it here!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=VQ.%3E%2B*%5C_25*d5O30*b4&input=4&debug=0)

## Explanation

```
VQ.>+*\_25*d5O30*b4  # Q = input

VQ                   # Repeat Q times
     *\_25           # 25 underscores
          *d5        # 5 spaces
    +                # concat the underscores and spaces
  .>         O25     # rotate this string 0-29 times
                *b4  # print the seperating newlines
```

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, <strike>74</strike> <strike>71</strike> 59

Thanks to Alex A. for reminding me that being basically one line means I can use the stabby lambda

```
f=->n{n.times{puts (('_'*25+' '*5)*2)[rand(30),30]+"\n"*5}}
```

Comment: `puts` adds a newline to the end (while Ruby's `print` doesn't), so it's been updated to `5` newlines.

Comment: All hail the `times` function for saving me 3 bytes over the `for` loop :D

Comment: 57 bytes: `->n{n.times{puts (('_'*25+' '*5)*2)[rand(30),30]+"\n"*5}}` [Try here](https://repl.it/BxTm/0)

Comment: You don't need to assign the lambda as part of the submission since we don't require functions to be named.

Comment: But then how am I supposed to call the function?

Comment: You can do `(->n{n.times{puts (('_'*25+' '*5)*2)[rand(30),30]+"\n"*5}})[input]` or just specify that you need to assign it in order to call it. This is quite common on the site.

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, 19 bytes

```
VQ.>r"5 25_"9O30*4b
```

[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=VQ.%3Er%225+25_%229O30%2a4b&input=4)

Thanks to FryAmTheEggman for catching a bug.

Comment: @AandN FryAmTheEggman is right, I have changed it to be randomly shifted by 0-29 characters instead of 0-25.

Answer (score 3):

## Julia, 72 bytes

```
n->join([join(circshift(["_"^25*" "^5...],rand(1:30)))"\n"^5 for i=1:n])
```

This is an anonymous function that accepts an integer and returns a string. To call it, assign it to a variable.

We construct a string of 25 underscores followed by 5 spaces, then splat that into an array of characters. We circularly shift it a random number of times (between 1 and 30), join it back into a string, and tack on 5 newlines. This process is repeated *n* times, where *n* is the input. The resulting array is joined and returned.

[Try it here](http://goo.gl/l4V3zc)

Answer (score 3):

## PowerShell 65 Bytes

```
0..$args[0]|%{-join("_"*25+" "*5)[($r=Random 25)..($r-29)];,""*5}
```

Run a loop for *n* iterations. Get a random number and make a underscore string with 5 spaces at the end. Index into the the string as an array to pull starting from a random location. Negative indexing wraps from the end. Join that back up again and append 5 newlines.

Edit: I don't know why I thought I needed the parameter for `-Maximum` as it's positional. Thanks to [TimmyD](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42963/timmyd) I shaved some bytes and forgot to get input so that drove me back up to 65.

Comment: @TimmyD I would be surprised if anyone still had 1.0. It was only available as a download and was not shipped with any OS. 2.0 should be considered the norm.

Comment: @TimmyD I do agree with that point just not where PowerShell __1.0__ is concerned. If anyone is on this site using using that it would surprise me. If I used a 3.0 or higher feature I would highlight that for sure.

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 23 bytes

```
:"95l25X"5Z"h30YrYS10ct
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=OiI5NWwyNVgiNVoiaDMwWXJZUzEwY3Q&input=NA)

#### Explanation

```
:"           % take input n implicitly. Repeat loop n times
  95l25X"    %   row vector with number 95 ('_') repeated 25 times
  5Z"        %   row vector of 5 blank spaces
  h          %   concatenate vertically
  30Yr       %   random number uniformly distributed on [1,2,...,30]
  YS         %   circularly shift
  10c        %   newline character. Includes another newline when printed
  t          %   duplicate
             % implicitly end loop and display stack contents
```

Answer (score 2):

### Java, <s>177</s> 140 bytes

*-1 byte to Blue moving the i++*

-2 bytes to me leaving meaningless whitespace in the original

-34 bytes to Blue for realizing I didn't need the char[] at all

[Because, ya know, Java.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5829)

```java
n->{String s="";for(;n-->0;){int r=(int)(Math.random()*30);for(int i=0;i<30;){s+=i>r&i<r+6|r>24&i++<=r%25?" ":"_";}s+="\n\n\n\n";}return s;}
```

Slightly ungolfed:

```java
Function<Integer, String> fallingBall = n -> {
    String s = "";
    for (;n-->0;) {
        int r = (int)(Math.random()*30);
        for (int i=0; i<30; i++) {
            s += i>r&i<r+6|r>24&i<=r%25?" ":"_";
        }
        s += "\n\n\n\n";
    }
    return s;
}
```

Since Java doesn't have a String 'rotate', I had to take a different approach. I generated a random int 0-29 that represents the start index of the hole (OBO because `>` is shorter than `>=`). Each individual character is then decided by the logic

```java
l[index] = (index>random && index<random+6) || (random>24 && index<=random%25) ? ' ' : '_';
```

This handles the "wrapping" nature of the whole.

Comment: By putting the i++ the last place i is used, you can save a byte.

Comment: Smart. Hacky, but smart. Smarter still is me somehow leaving meaningless whitespace at the beginning of my snippet (`s = ""`). Both are fixed now.

Comment: You can also save a bunch more by getting rid of the char array, change the char literals to string literals, and use s+= in the inside for loop. I just tested it

Comment: Btw great answer

Comment: That's what I get for focusing on one way to do it. -34(!) bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## SpecBAS - 93 bytes

```
1 a$="_"*25+" "*5: INPUT n: FOR i=1 TO n: r=1+INT(RND*30): ?a$(r TO)+a$( TO r-1)''''': NEXT i
```

Makes a string of 25 underscores + 5 spaces, picks a random start point and splices the string at that position and tacks the start of string to end.

The apostrophe forces a newline, so 1 at end of string and 4 empty lines.

Answer (score 1):

## Python, <s>119</s> 103 bytes

```
import random
s='_'*20+' '*5
def f(n,a=random.randint(0,25)):[print(s[a:]+s[:a]+3*'\n')for _ in' '*n]
```

Comment: Your latest update doesn't work because you've put the random in a default argument, so the function will always output the same row `n` times

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3.5 - <strike>109</strike> 113 bytes (+4 for printing out 4 new lines between each result):

```
def g(a,j='_'*25+' '*5):
 for l in range(a):import random;n=random.randrange(len(j)+1);print(j[-n:]+j[:-n]+'\r'*4)
```

## Ungolfed Form:

```
# j is the starting string with the 25 underscores and then 5 spaces at the end
def g(a,j='_'*25+' '*5):
    import random #Import the random module
    for l in range(a): # Do the following as many times as provided by the user
        n=random.randrange(len(j)+1) Get a random number in the range 0-29
        print(j[-n:]+j[:-n]+'\r'*4) #Shift the string characters right "n" times and print out the results with 4 new lines in between
```

Basically what is going on is that a string 'j', consisting of 25 underscore followed by 5 spaces, is given as an argument to the function "g". Then, the random module is imported, and, as many times as specified by the user, a random number is chosen in the range `0 => 29`, and the string, "j", is shifted right that many times. The result is then printed out after each iteration, with 4 new lines in between each result.

Comment: Does this also print the newlines in between?

Comment: @AandN Now it does. :)

Comment: You actually need to print 4 newlines :p. So changing `'\r'` to `'\r'*4` should probably work. Also, I think you can change `range(a+1)` to `range(a)`.

Comment: @AandN Actually,  using `range(a)` actually prints out `a-1` number of lines, so `range(a+1)` is the best way to print out the exact number of lines the user provides. Also, it now prints 4 new lines in between each result.

Comment: Hmmm, that is weird, because I tested this with `g(5)` and it prints 6 strings instead of five, so changing `a+1` to `a` would probably fix that.

Comment: @AandN Actually, I just tested it right now, and you're right! I actually  forgot that, even though it starts from 0 and goes up to 9, that's still 10 numbers. Therefore, I have now corrected by golfed code. It should work perfectly now. :)

Comment: That saves 2 bytes :). It's a very nice answer!

Comment: @AandN Thanks! I really appreciate that!